# Javascript - Form Submit not stopping

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form I'm trying to stop users from double-submitting using javascript. For some reason,even when the handler function returns false and event.preventDefault are called, the form will still submit multiple times. Anyone know why? Also how do I make this work as intended?

```js
document.getElementById('my_form').addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
    if ( validationFunction(document.getElementById('submit_button')) == false) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Function
validationFunction(){
return false
}

```
<form method="post" id="my_form">
  <input name='textbox'>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_button">
</form>
```

Comment: What's going on in `validationFunction`? Is it checking if the form was already submitted? You don't need to post the whole thing, just enough so that it's a [mcve].

Comment: validation function is returning true or false

Comment: Yes, that was clear from the code above ;). It's still not enough to reproduce the problem. Could you post enough code to make your example **Complete** (see the link in my previous comment)?

Answer (score 1):

Try it in simple way. Like this

HTML

```
<form id="my_form">
<input name='textbox'>
<input type="button"  id="submit_btn">
</form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("submit_btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById("my_form").submit(); // if validation is true run this
});
```

Comment: Nope. Must use addEventListener

Comment: Now you're not stopping the submit. DX

Comment: What is the actual problem?  how it is submitting multiple times?  You can use ajax if you have to do some validation before post. Instead of form submit.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion one of the other devs had bound another function to the click.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('my_form').addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
  if ( validationFunction(document.getElementById('submit_button')) == false) {

        // anything here

        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    // anything here

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: won't this always kill the event?

Comment: What do you mean by "kill the event"?

Comment: it will never properly execute. because you're preventing the default. My understanding is that you want to do this as you return false.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "execute properly". Event.preventDefault() cancels the event if it is cancelable, **without stopping** further propagation of the event. For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I want to cancel the event where RETURN FALSE is, when validation fails. not all the time no matter what.

Comment: @catbadger, check the edit. What I have right now is no different from what I had earlier. `event.preventDefault();` does not kill the event, it simply prevents default behavior of the form submission event, without stopping further propagation of the event.